# How to close tab range by tab/buffer number

Tags: firefox, vimperator

In vimperator I often have 20+ tabs open. To get a list of my tabs I press "B" which shows the buffer/tab numbers.

So I want to do something like :3,5bd to delete tabs 3 to 5. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about closing tabs in Vimperator in the [Vimperator's help file](http://vimperator.org/help/vimperator/tabs.xhtml#closing-tabs).

As it comes to the actual question, I don't think you can do exactly that - with that specific syntax, at least. However, to close tabs 3 through 5 is possible with `3gt 3d`.

So, first you have to change to the first tab to be closed *and* do some math yourself (how many tabs you want to close: 5-3 + 1 = 3).

Comment: I wonder if you could make a vimperator function to delete a tab range without leaving the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `:tabgroups` command to group tabs and then remove whole group.

You can find out about `tabgroups` using `:help tabgroups`

Answer (score 0):

To remove tabs by pattern you can use:

```
:bd "<wow I have 200 tabs open with oracle support>"
:bd support
```